# How to populate two things in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

This is my chat schema

```
const chatModel = mongoose.Schema(
  {
    chatName: { type: String, trim: true },
    isGroupChat: { type: Boolean, default: false },
    users: [
      { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "consumer" },
      { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "technician" },
    ],
    latestMessage: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "Message",
    },
    groupAdmin: [
      { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "technician" },
      { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "consumer" },
    ],
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);
```

And this is my controller function method to find and populate

```
 const FullChat = await chatDB.findOne({ _id: createdChat._id }).populate({
        path: "users",
        populate: [{ path: "consumer" }, { path: "technician" }],
      });
```

Now the issue is that I get the result but it is populating only the first element of array. which is I am getting only the consumer data not the technician .